# I want to print a pattern with emojis

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code for a pattern to log into the console. it works just fine with & and * symbols but when I want to replace & with  and replace * with  , the code no longer works properly. what should I do?

```js
function pattern(n) {
  for (let i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log("&".repeat(i).padStart(n, "*"));
  }
}
pattern(5);
```

Comment: It's probably due to  and  have a length of 2

Comment: Emoji are outside the basic multilingual plane, and javascript counts unicode code-units, not codepoints. Easiest way around would be to not use `String.prototype.padStart` (which explicitly counts string length, code-units), but another `repeat`: `console.log(''.repeat(i) + ''.repeat(n - i));`

Comment: @ASDFGerte I changed your code into this one below to get the exact same result I intended to get. it worked perfectly.   console.log("".repeat(n - i) + "".repeat(i));      thanks!